# Having an issue with textures and UV mapping

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

So I have been following this video in order to UV map my Arcade Box.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k

I manage to unwrap and make sure nothing is stretched out as shown.
[image: unwrapping]

Now I try to put an image and place the needed faces to match the picture, not only does it not show anything even in textured view but it is also stretching my uv maps?
[image]

Is there any advice to first:
Be able to see the demo version of what I am putting on as a texture?
Keep the UV_wrapping from stretching out?

I know there is probably a simple solution for this but I don't think I am typing the right key words to find the solution :(.

Answer (score 1):

Your texture is distorted, because your image texture is in 2:1 aspect ratio, and your original UV map in 1:1 aspect ratio.

Either manually scale the UV map to half it's width.
Or use the *Mapping node's* Scale panel to correct for the distortion.

[image]